# uncaughtException: Error: . is neither a posix nor a windows path, and there is no 'join' method defined in the file system

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, next.js, next.js13

I'm using **nextjs 13.5.6** with **app router and app directory**.
This error occurs when compiling `app/(home)/page.js` route. Folder and file structure in app folder is as follows:

```
app/
-(home)/page.js
-services/page.js
-portfolio/page.js
-contact/page.js
-about/page.js
-globals.css
-layout.js
-favicon.ico
```

My node version is 18.16.0
I have defined RootLayout for all pages in `app/layout.js` file.

I've tried deleting `.next` folder and running server again but it does'nt work

Comment: Please show your code that's getting the error.

Answer (score 1):

Just had this same problem when going through a tutorial. I would get this while trying to move the existing default page.js (home page) into a new /(main)/(routes) folder, if you are also trying to move the file into a new path, you should instead try just creating a new page.js, and populate with the contents of your page.js, you can then just delete the existing page.js since the project is looking for `function Home()` for the main page. I did not have to, but delete .next for good measure and recompile. Hope this helps!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

try to change the name of route on which this compiling error is coming and then
delete .next folder and then start it , i am getting same error on my profile page route i change its name to me and then delete .next and then run it again , i do it 2 times for 1st time it dosent work