# Next.js 13 - Error: . is neither a posix nor a windows path, and there is no 'join' method defined in the file system

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-router

I'm using **Next.js 13.5.4** with the app directory. I'm trying to use [route groups](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-groups#creating-multiple-root-layouts) to have multiple root layouts, but I'm encountering an error.

Here is my app directory excluding api routes:

```
app
├───(main)
│   │   globals.css
│   │   layout.tsx
│   │   page.tsx
│   │
│   ├───login
│   │       page.tsx
│   │
│   └───mytree
│           page.tsx
│
├───(preview)
│   │   layout.tsx
│   │
│   └───preview
│           page.tsx
│
└───api
    Not relevant
```

Here is the content of my `app/(main)/page.tsx` file:

```
import Hero from "@/components/landing/Hero";
import Footer from "@/components/layout/Footer";
import NavBar from "@/components/layout/NavBar";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="absolute z-10 w-full">
        <NavBar />
      </div>
      <div className="flex flex-col min-h-screen">
        <div className="pt-20" />
        <div className="flex-grow flex items-center justify-center">
          <Hero />
        </div>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

And here is the error message again:

```
Error: . is neither a posix nor a windows path, and there is no 'join' method defined in the file system
```

The error occurs when I try to compile the `app/(main)/page.tsx` route, but does not occur when compiling the `app/(main)/mytree/page.tsx` route or the `app/(preview)/preview/page.tsx` route.

I tried renaming the `(main)` group as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77369284/uncaughtexception-error-is-neither-a-posix-nor-a-windows-path-and-there-is), and I tried deleting the `.next` directory and restarting the dev server multiple times. I also tried upgrading to Next.js 14, but that didn't help either.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What does `app/(main)/page.tsx` look like?

Comment: @machineghost I updated the question to include the `app/(main)/page.tsx` file

Comment: Everything looks fine to me.  I'd recommend creating a super-simplified copy of your project and sharing it as part of a bug for Next.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the error by creating a new Next project with `npx create-next-app@13.5.4` and copying the old project's contents into the new project. I'm still unsure what caused the error.

Answer (score 0):

- This error occurs when you move `page.tsx / layout.tsx` file to a different folder. In your case, I assume you might have moved `page.tsx & layout.tsx` file from the app directory to `(main)` folder.
- If you’re encountering this error and are using tools like GitHub or GitLab, **you can resolve it by removing your local project and re-cloning it from the remote repository**. Please ensure that all changes have been pushed to the remote repository before deleting the local project.
- To prevent this error, instead of moving the file to a different folder, you could create a new file in the folder you prefer and then copy the contents of the file you wish to move into it.